# Can't load css and js files with docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am new to docker and i ran into a problem when i call css and javascript files in php file i found that they are not loaded

Following my code:
`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  php-env:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: airline
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    environment:
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
```

`dockerfile`

```
FROM php:8.0-apache
WORKDIR /var/www/html
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y libmariadb-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
```

**my file layout is like this**

```
-resources
--app.css
--app.js
-src
--index.php
```

I'm fetching the css file like this: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/app.css">`

The error I get when I go to the css or js file is:

**Not found**

*The requested URL was not found on this server.*

*Apache/2.4.54 (Debian) Server at localhost Port 8080*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to get it working on my end, here is the application I created:

`/src/index.php`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/app.css">
<?php ?>
<p>Hello World</p>
```

`/resources/app.css`:

```css
p {
    color: #FF0000
}
```

---

Here are the changes I made to the `docker-compose.yml` and `Dockerfile` to get it working:

`docker-compose.yml`

1. Removed the volume binding for php-env service (since we are going to copy this in the Dockerfile)

```html
version: '3.9'

services:
  php-env:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: airline
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    environment:
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
```

`Dockerfile`

1. Copied the `/src` directory into `/var/www/html`
2. Copied the `/resources` directory into `/var/www/html/resources`

```html
FROM php:8.0-apache
WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY ./src ./
COPY ./resources ./resources
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y libmariadb-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
```

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying; Do I have to write like this as an example?

volumes:
          - ./src:/var/www/html
          - ./resources:/var/www/html

I tried this but I still get the same error.

Comment: kinda, you can’t mount two directories to the same volume, but you can copy the folders over in the Dockerfile, will edit my answer with how I think it could be done

Comment: @JFeel Please look at my edited answer and let me know if any more problems

Comment: yes it is working now thank you very much. I have one last question, will I apply the same procedure when I add another file?

Comment: @JFeel No problem :) The `COPY ./resources ./resources` line in the `Dockerfile` should now cover any new files/folders added inside of your `/resources` directory. If you decide to put them in another folder, you'll have to add another line to your Dockerfile.